# Weird scrolling container when using Auto Height in Fullpage Wordpress plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins, height

When I use fp auto height from the Fullpage Plugin (Auto Height checked in options) for one section and add text which is bigger then a section it fits the section to the whole screen and starts scrolling inside.

[example here](http://photography-template.lukaskuhn.me) (the second section)

I want it to be bigger then the other sections...

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the plugin?

Comment: It appears that what you're requesting is not a feature of of the Fullpage plugin. Do you have the ability to write custom JS for your theme?